# How do I use the computer?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do I use the computer after finishing the game? It says "Press return to continue".  I tried to press it but it doesn't do anything.  Does anybody know how to access it?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Would you be able to define "it"?  Did you press your ENTER key?  Or did you click on the text on the screen?  You can edit your post to add more information using the edit link above.

Answer (score 1):

You click enter and then help to see a list of commands.
then type "help *command name*" to see how to type it in.